# Why am I not getting any device token after registering with APNS for push notifications?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have this code that asks the user to allow my app to receive push notes.

The permission part of it works fine but I never get a device token or any error after I allow the app to receive push notifications.

This is my AppDelegate file:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate{
    
    var window: UIWindow?
    
    
  func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
      launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
      
      
   
      registerForPushNotifications()
      
      let notificationOption = launchOptions?[.remoteNotification]
      
    
      if
        let notification = notificationOption as? [String: AnyObject],
        let aps = notification["aps"] as? [String: AnyObject] {
        
        (window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController)?.selectedIndex = 1
      }
      
    return true
  }
    
    
    
    func registerForPushNotifications() {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { (granted, error) in
            print("Permission granted: \(granted)")
            guard granted else { return }
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings { (settings) in
                print("Notification settings: \(settings)")
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func getNotificationSettings() {
           UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings { (settings) in
               print("Notification settings: \(settings)")
           }
       }

       func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                        didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
           let tokenParts = deviceToken.map { data -> String in
               return String(format: "%02.2hhx", data)
           }

           let token = tokenParts.joined()
           print("Device Token: \(token)")
       }

       func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                        didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
           print("Failed to register: \(error)")
       }
    
    
}
```

I've tried different variations of the same code and still getting no device token. Ive enabled the Push notifications in my project in Xcode and I restarted the my device a few times too.

**EDIT:**

The `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` and `didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError` are never called for some reason!

Because I am not getting any error or device token at all!

Comment: Please make sure that device is connected with internet

Comment: @vikasprajapati, thats the first thing I checked.

Comment: You do not need user permissions to *receive* push notifications. You need user permission to *display* notifications. So, while you do need the permission request code that you have shown, you should not conditionally call `registerForRemoteNotifications`. You should call this function in `didFinishLaunching` every time your application starts and ask for permission to display if you need it